# report from binary file c++ - turbo c

Tags: c++

I am working on c++ and turbo c.

I want to show all records that submitted to binary file, but my codes just show second record and don't show all record.
for example if you add 10 records to the file, in the report show 10 records but **they are one** and just repeated to this 10 lines.

My codes

```
//My struct
struct {
 char name[20];
 char id[2];
 char publisher[20];} books, listbooks[100];

//Codes for add records to file
   FILE *pt;
 pt=fopen("books.dat","a");
 clrscr();
  printf("\t Please Enter Data for new book");
  printf("\n Please enter Name:");
  scanf("%s", &books.name );
  printf("Please enter ID:");
  scanf("%s", &books.id);
  printf("Please enter Publisher:");
  scanf("%s", &books.publisher);
fwrite(&books, sizeof(books), 1,pt);
fclose(pt);

//Codes for show report
 FILE *pt;
 pt=fopen("books.dat","r");
 int i=0;
 printf("Book Name: \t\t\t");
 printf("Book ID: \t\t\t");
 printf("Book Publisher: \n");
 do{
  i++;
  fseek (pt,sizeof(listbooks[i]), 0);
  fread(&listbooks[i], sizeof(listbooks[i]), i,pt);
    printf("%s \t\t\t\t", listbooks[i].name);
    printf("%s \t\t\t\t", listbooks[i].id);
    printf("%s \n", listbooks[i].publisher);
    if(i>=4) break;
 }while(!feof(pt));
```

My problem is in "//Codes for show report" block and please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: 1) Turbo C does not do C++. 2) Turbo C++ does not come close to modern C++ and learning Turbo C++ is a disservice to yourself. 3) this does not look like C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your do while loop you are always `fseek`ing to sizeof(your record type). This means the subsequent `fread` will always read the second record in the file.

Remove the call to `fseek`.